# Custom toast : Error on findViewById(R.id.toast)

Tags: android, toast

I am trying to make Custom Toast but I am receiving the following error:

> cannot find symbol
>   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_root));

At the same time `findViewById()` could be seen in other lines of the code.
What is my mistake?

```
public class MyCustomToast extends Toast {


public MyCustomToast(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public static Toast customToast(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {



    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_root));

    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skipper_toast);

    TextView text_toast = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
    text_toast.setText(text);

    Toast toast = new Toast(context);

    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(duration);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();

    return toast;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you should alter your code:

```
public class MyCustomToast extends Toast {


public MyCustomToast(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public static Toast customToast(Activity activity, CharSequence text, int duration) {



    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.toast_root));

    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.skipper_toast);

    TextView text_toast = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
    text_toast.setText(text);

    Toast toast = new Toast(context);

    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(duration);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();

    return toast;
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am a new in Android environment.Could you provide me with more detailed answer and explanations.Thank you.

Comment: Egor, how I then will define Activity in MainActivitymct = new MyCustomToast(context);

Comment: Sorry, to call method mct.customToast(activity, "Че нада", 300);

Comment: should I do it like activity = new Activity(); but app can not be launched on emulator.

Comment: @user1706819, If you're calling this from the Activity, then it should look like MyCustomToast.customToast(this, "String", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();